# rpmbuild setting wrong file ownership says root:root (wrong owner/group build:users)

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, rpmbuild

I am creating a bunch of files and directories on a target machine using RPMs, each of which have a different set of file/dir permissions. I have created a spec file, which builds this RPM.
The spec file looks as below:

```
Name:            testMultipleFiles
Version:         1.0
Release:         2
Summary:         Demo how to package multiple files
Group:           DCCA Deployment
License:         GPLv2
Source:          testMultipleFiles.tar.gz
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-build
AutoReqProv:    on

%description

Authors:
--------
    Name Raj Kumar Sanpui
%prep
%setup -q

%build

%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir1
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir2
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir3
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir4

mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir5
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir6
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir7

mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir8
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir9
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir10

install file1.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir1
install file2.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir2
install file3.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir3
install file4.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir4

install file5.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir5
install file6.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/insiteone/dir6


%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%post

%postun


%files
%defattr(644,insite1,insite1,0755)
/opt/insiteone/dir1/file1.sh
/opt/insiteone/dir2/file2.sh
/opt/insiteone/dir3/file3.sh

%attr(644,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir4/file4.sh
%attr(644,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir5/file5.sh
%attr(644,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir6/file6.sh

%dir %attr(777,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir4
%dir %attr(700,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir5
%dir %attr(644,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir6
%dir %attr(640,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir7
%dir %attr(600,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir8
%dir %attr(744,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir9
%dir %attr(644,insite1,insite1)/opt/insiteone/dir10
```

However, when i build this RPM, there are no errors and the build succeeds but the build log says:

```
Checking permissions and ownerships - using the permissions files
        /tmp/Check.perms.gv6tJD
setting /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/ to root:root 0755. (wrong owner/group build:users)
setting /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt to root:root 0755. (wrong owner/group build:users)
```

which means, it is setting to root:root instead of insite1:insite1 as the user and group.

Here is the full build log.

```
build@SLES11SP4-185:~/rpmbuild/SPECS> rpmbuild -bb testmulti.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.14760
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/build/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd /home/build/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf testMultipleFiles-1.0
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/build/rpmbuild/SOURCES/testMultipleFiles.tar.gz
+ tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd testMultipleFiles-1.0
++ /usr/bin/id -u
+ '[' 1001 = 0 ']'
++ /usr/bin/id -u
+ '[' 1001 = 0 ']'
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.14760
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/build/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ /bin/rm -rf /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build
++ dirname /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build
+ /bin/mkdir -p /var/tmp
+ /bin/mkdir /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build
+ cd testMultipleFiles-1.0
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.14760
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/build/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd testMultipleFiles-1.0
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir1
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir2
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir3
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir4
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir5
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir6
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir7
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir8
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir9
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir10
+ install file1.sh /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir1
+ install file2.sh /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir2
+ install file3.sh /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir3
+ install file4.sh /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir4
+ install file5.sh /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir5
+ install file6.sh /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt/insiteone/dir6
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-lib64-linux
sf@suse.de: if you find problems with this script, drop me a note
+ RPM_BUILD_ROOT=/var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build
+ export RPM_BUILD_ROOT
+ test -x /usr/sbin/Check -a 1001 = 0 -o -x /usr/sbin/Check -a '!' -z /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build
+ echo 'I call /usr/sbin/Check...'
I call /usr/sbin/Check...
+ /usr/sbin/Check
Checking permissions and ownerships - using the permissions files
        /tmp/Check.perms.gv6tJD
setting /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/ to root:root 0755. (wrong owner/group build:users)
setting /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/opt to root:root 0755. (wrong owner/group build:users)
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-symlink
Processing files: testMultipleFiles-1.0-2
Finding  Provides: /usr/lib/rpm/find-provides testMultipleFiles
Finding  Requires: /usr/lib/rpm/find-requires testMultipleFiles
Finding  Supplements: /usr/lib/rpm/find-supplements testMultipleFiles
Requires(interp): /bin/sh /bin/sh
Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1 rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
Requires(post): /bin/sh
Requires(postun): /bin/sh
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build
Wrote: /home/build/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/testMultipleFiles-1.0-2.x86_64.rpm
Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.14760
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/build/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd testMultipleFiles-1.0
+ rm -rf /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build
+ exit 0
```

**Please note:** The insite1:insite1 user and groups will be present in target machine beforehand, the RPM is installed, and it's not something present in RPM build machine, as there is no reason for me to create them.

**Addition:** I observed, it goes ahead and installs all files and directories fine with appropriate permissions, in a target machine which has user and group present (insite1:insite1), **however the directories dir1, dir2, and dir3 are still set as root:root** but 0755, i was expecting it to be insite1:insite1 based on `%defattr` set. **Isn't there no way to set default directory permissions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put in `%files`:

```
/opt/insiteone/dir1/file1.sh
```

That means that in rpm get only the `file1.sh`. And the defattr applies to only that file. Of course the file comes with some path. So if the path does not exist, it is created. With current user (usually root).

So you either should say:

```
%files
/opt/insiteone/dir1
```

Which will take dir1 and everything within it (recursively).
Or:

```
%files
%dir /opt/insiteone/dir1
/opt/insiteone/dir1/file1.sh
```

BTW correct package should check if user and group "insite1" exist. You can do that using this %pre snippet https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:UsersAndGroups?rd=Packaging/UsersAndGroups#Dynamic_allocation

Comment: Thanks that partially solves the problem, `dir1`, `dir2`, and `dir3` now installs with `insite1:insite1` but still while building the same error comes: `setting /var/tmp/testMultipleFiles-1.0-build/ to root:root 0755. (wrong owner/group build:users)`